# what can be done to fix this error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/sourabh/prozilla-2.0.4'
Making all in intl
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/sourabh/prozilla-2.0.4/intl'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/sourabh/prozilla-2.0.4/intl'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sourabh/prozilla-2.0.4/po'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/sourabh/prozilla-2.0.4/po'
Making all in libprozilla
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sourabh/prozilla-2.0.4/libprozilla'
cd . && /home/sourabh/prozilla-2.0.4/libprozilla/missing automake-1.4 --gnu Makefile
WARNING:`automake-1.4' is needed, and you do not seem to have it handy on your
         system.  You might have modified some files without having the
         proper tools for further handling them.  Check the `README' file,
         it often tells you about the needed prerequirements for installing
         this package.  You may also peek at any GNU archive site, in case
         some other package would contain this missing`automake-1.4' program.
make[2]: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sourabh/prozilla-2.0.4/libprozilla'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/sourabh/prozilla-2.0.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install autotools-dev` and `sudo apt-get install automake` before making again

Answer (score 2):

Its because it's expecting automake1.4. So we need to install automake-1.4,

Follow these steps to fix the error,

$wget http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/automake/automake1.4_1.4-p6-13.1_all.deb

$sudo dpkg -i automake1.4_1.4-p6-13.1_all.deb

$sudo update-alternatives --config automake

There are 2 choices for the alternative automake (providing /usr/bin/automake).

### Selection    Path                    Priority   Status

- 0            /usr/bin/automake-1.14   32        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/automake-1.14   32        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/automake-1.4    20        manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2

update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/automake-1.4 to provide /usr/bin/automake (automake) in manual mode

Select 1.4

Then do configure and other steps.